# launching app or opening link in safari from ios framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods, ios-frameworks

I am developing an ios framework (which can be installed using cocoapods). When a method of this framework is called, it will open a url on safari. If some other app is able to handle that url using universal link, then it would launch that app.

I was trying to call (in ios 9.3 simulator with target deployment ios 8.0

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Above code works perfectly in any ios app. But when I placed same code in my framework which is included in another app, it gives exception and app crashes.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString scheme]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc070717e00'
```

Do things work differently inside framework? what would be correct way. In this example I was trying to open regular https link.

Thanks

Comment: What's your target platform and deployment target? That second method is available since iOS 10.

Comment: target deployment is ios 8.0, I was running it in simulator ios 9.3. I have tried first one first. Both did not work.

Comment: Then please show the exact usage and exact error message using the first method.

Comment: Thanks! I have updated the question.

Comment: It looks like you're calling with the wrong argument. Probably you pass an NSString where a NSURL is asked for.

Comment: Oh yes! Thats it. It worked after I converted it to NSURL. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Great, I wrapped it up in an answer, maybe it's helpful for others in the future, as this is easy to get wrong. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this might be useful to others, here's what seems have to caused the problem:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

was called with an argument that actually wasn't an `NSURL`, but an `NSString`, hence an `NSInvalidArgumentException` was thrown in the process - with a hint in the description for the wrong type.

The compiler should issue at least a warning here, though.

Before the edit, an alternative method was mentioned:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url options:nil completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
    NSLog(@"opened url %d", success);
}];
```

The reason for this to fail was different: that method is only available since iOS 10, hence an `NSInvalidArgumentException` was thrown on the testing environment running iOS 9.3.

Comment: can it be called in any thread or it should be called in main thread only?

Comment: I am not sure, and couldn't find an answer. Conceptionally, I think I'd schedule those calls on the main thread anyway, as it will most probably interact with the application life cycle (which should happen on the main thread). But no hard evidence here.

Comment: Thanks for insights! Will try to find answer